# why mysql and hibernate return incorrect date in the code(-1 day at 18:00:00)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date

I have a little problem with mysql + hibernate.
in the database I have:
[image: records from DB]

I don't have any record of January 13th 2023

if I perform a query to get this information of the January 14th 2023, in the code I get this:

[image: date in the code]

I don't know why if in the database I have 14-jan-23 in the code I get: 13-jan-23 18:00:00

I thing that it's a configuration problem, in the hibernate.cfg.xml I have:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metsa?serverTimezone=UTC</property>
```

any one knows what I have wrong?

I tried to change the time zone in mysql, but doesn't matter what I set, always I have the same date in the code -1 day at 18:00:00

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
SET @@session.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Comment: What is the time zone of the process, i.e. what is the value of the java system property `user.timezone`?

Comment: user.timezone = "America/Mexico_City"

Comment: Mexico citiy is UTC-6, i.e. has exactly the 6-hour offset we observe. I would recommend to either convert the date to `UTC`or configure the `user.timezone` to `UTC` (Warning: configuring `user.timezone` will change all time and date information for the whole application, e.g. log timestamps will also be represented in the configured timezone).

Comment: I did that, but doesn't work, but I tried with this and now works fine:

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this adding this in the date field:

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)